# Why is this MySQL query case sensitive?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a query on my MySQL database. I want it to be case insensitive. If "RED" exists in the database and I search for "red", I want the result to show.

Unfortunately, this query is being case-senstivie and I dont know why:

```
$color = "red";
$size = "large";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE color = '$color' OR size = '$size'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    if ($color == $row['color']) {
        echo "The color exists in the database";
    }
    if ($size == $row['size']) {
        echo "The size exists in the database";
    }

}
```

Using this example, "RED" exists in the database, but it's not being found.

What's wrong with the query?

Comment: Show your `SHOW CREATE TABLE items`

Comment: Show the create table and we can tell you how to change it to make it not case sensitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the collation of you column is case sensitive

Comment: ... or collation for the whole table

Comment: Do what zerkms asked - that will help

Comment: any collation that ends in `_ci` usually means case insensitive, for instance `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Thanks. I tried `utf8_unicode_ci` and `utf8_general_ci` and neither worked.

Answer (score 2):

Case sensitivity is determined by the collation of the column / default collation for the table & database

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `REGEXP` operator which is case insensitive. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html .

Comment: Can you be more specific? I welcome criticism if it's constructive.

Comment: `regexp` cannot be optimized ever. And mysql has built-in facility to compare in case-insensitive way. So don't see any reason to prefer slow solution over fast

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware that MySQL cannot optimize regular expression lookups.

Comment: it's not mysql's drawback. No RDBMS can optimize it

Comment: Technically, they should be able to optimize simple cases such as this though, whether any actually do so or not.

Comment: if they optimized this case - then it would work like `=`, which didn't work for OP. Still not a lot of sense :-) PS: "You can use the REGEXP operator which is case insensitive" --- `=` is insensitive as well

Comment: Not to drag this out, but I believe the collation orders all put upper/lower case characters next to each other, so I would think that a case insensitive search could be optimized even for a column that is defined as case sensitive.

Comment: and even if it was true "but I believe the collation orders all put upper/lower case characters next to each other" - then comparison by `=` would be anyway better than `regex`. So still don't see any reason to use it in this case